# Remove string from textarea using regular expressions

Tags: jquery, regex

```
<textarea name="test">
  test
  [url=http://test.com]test[/url]
  [url][img]http://test.com/test.jpg[/img][/url]
  test
</textarea>
```

How can I remove everything everything wrapped within the `[url][/url]` and `[url=][/url]` but keep the `[img]`?

What I've tried:

```
var value = $('textarea[name="test"]').val();
value = value.replace(/\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/g, '');
value = value.replace(/\[url=(.+?)\]/g, '');
value = value.replace('[url]', '');
value = value.replace('[\/url]', '');
$('textarea[name="test"]').val(value);
```

Expected output:

```
<textarea>
  test

  [img]http://test.com/test.jpg[/img]
  test
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should sort you out - it can be achieved with one regex replace:

```
var value = $('textarea[name="test"]').val();
value = value.replace(/\[\/?url([^\]]+)?\]/g, '');
$('textarea[name="test"]').val(value);
```

[jsFiddle Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/toomanyredirects/Y667D/).

What's essentially happening there is the regular expression looks for a string that starts with a square bracket, `[`, which may or may not be followed by a closing `/`, but is followed by `url`, and then it will continue matching until it encounters a `]`, and won't care what it finds to that point. That way you get matches for all of the following:

- `[url]`
- `[/url]`
- `[url=http://www.google.com]`
- `[url hello world this is nice]` (if you really want :-P)

I noted above that you change the name of your `textarea` field in the jQuery from 'text' to 'signature' but never posted the HTML containing the second textarea - I've just used the same one - 'test' in my code above.

Hope that helps.